# Simple project management---org-mode, or another tool?

Tags: org-mode, project

I'm a beginning emacs and org-mode user interested in the mode for personal project management. For example, I have a database of photo images:

- 2014-10-steven-and-his-cats.jpg
- 2014-10-steven-author-photo.jpg
- 2014-11-james-with-his-giant-peach.tif

Etc, for hundreds (not thousands) of pictures. I'd like to treat this as a database from which I could draw information for various (fairly simple, some longterm) projects. I'm wondering if people employ org-mode to organize data in this way using, for instance, org links, or if there's a better tool than org-mode. I have limited technical expertise, and am not a programmer.

Comment: One word: Icicles.

Comment: maybe a different approach would [do](http://t-o-c-c.com) ?

Comment: It would probably help if you define more clearly what you mean by "project" here.

Comment: One "for instance": I record videos and take photos of bands, and sometimes pull from what I have to create video projects for those groups. These video and image files sometimes live in different directories, sometimes the same, but always on the same hard drive.

Comment: The statement about you having limited technical expertise and not being a programer is fine *so long as* you are willing to learn a little `elisp` to customize various aspects of Emacs.  If you have some OCD in you (like me), then be prepared to spend an *enormous* amount of time learning `elisp` so that you can customize Emacs to meet your precise personal needs.

Comment: I've just begun going through the "Emacs Lisp Intro" info node on emacs. It is hard for me, but I can tell that it will be of great value as I move forward with the program. That plus my OCD. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is one piece of an approach to organizing. No doubt it can be used together with other organizing approaches.

1. Put libraries [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) and [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) in your `load-path` (i.e., "install" them), and load them (`require`) when you start Emacs.
2. Put your image files in one or more directories. You can take advantage of the directory structure as a first level of organization. (You probably do this already.)
3. In any such directory, use `C-u C-u C-M-b` to [*automatically bookmark each file*](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkingFilesYouCannotVisitWithEmacs) in the directory in a bookmark file whose name you specify, and create a *bookmark for that bookmark-file*.
4. You can later **"jump" to that bookmark-file bookmark**, to load its set of
   bookmarks.  If you use `C-u` when you jump to it, then you [*switch*
   bookmark files](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkingFilesYouCannotVisitWithEmacs), so that `C-x p e` (or `C-x r l`) displays only the
   bookmarks created from the files in that directory.

   (Without `C-u`, jumping
   to the bookmark-file bookmark simply loads its bookmarks into the
   current set of bookmarks. That is, instead of switching, it adds the bookmarked bookmark-file's bookmarks to the current set of bookmarks.)

   Using different bookmark files (e.g. via different bookmark-file bookmarks) is a powerful way to organize sets of bookmarks, bringing one or the other set into focus.
5. When you bookmark a file that Emacs recognizes as an image file 
   or a sound file, an appropriate handler is used automatically. That means that "jumping" to an image-file bookmark automatically displays the image.
6. After you create individual bookmarks for, say, music or image
   files, you can use `P B` in the bookmark-list display to show only
   those bookmarks, and then use `C-x r m` to [*bookmark that state of
   the bookmark-list*](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkListViews). In other words, even if your image files are mixed in with other stuff in the same directory, you can create a bookmark that shows only the image files, and later "jump" to it, to restore that display.  This gives you a "playlist" of music or a "slideshow" of images.
7. You can [***tag*** any bookmark](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags).  A tag is just an arbitrary string (or it is a string together with an associated Lisp value).  You use tags for classifying, searching, and accessing bookmarks. In this case, the bookmarks are your image files (they are autofile bookmarks) - and perhaps also your bookmark-file bookmarks (each of which is a collection of image-file bookmarks, these sets possibly overlapping). You might have tags representing different characteristics of the images: date, subject matter, occasion, etc.
8. In addition to tagging a bookmark with any number of tags, you can **annotate** it with a textual description. By default, this text is in **Org mode**, which gives you yet another way to organize information about your image files.
9. You can also bookmark a Dired buffer itself - or a Dired tree (directory and its descendents).  This records the `ls` switches, which files are marked, which subdirectories are inserted, and which (sub)directories are hidden.  That too gives you a means of organization and access.

Comment: I've heard about "bookmarks" and "tags" but never until now understood the relationship between them. I'll install bookmarks+ and give it a try to see if it fits my use-cases.

Comment: Caveat: Emacs tags are not the same thing as **Bookmark+** tags. For info about Emacs tags, see the Emacs manual, node [`Tags`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html). **Bookmark+** tags are like I said - they are similar to [delicious.com](https://delicious.com/) tags. See [Bookmark Tags](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags).

Comment: I'm presently strategizing around these ideas. One question: on the Bookmark+ page of EmacsWiki it says, "If you also use library Dired+ (dired+.el) then you can use `C-+` to add tags to the marked files and `C--` to remove tags from them." This is operating on marked files in a `dired` buffer, I believe? When I invoke `C-+` in a `dired` buffer with marked files, I get "C-+ is undefined" in the minibuffer. I would love to add tags (while presumably simultaneously creating autofile bookmarks) to marked files in a dired buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a list of files in a project, [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) is a currently a popular project manager in Emacs. If you use a version control system (i.e. Git), Projectile automatically recognizes it as a project and gives you a list of files with `projectile-find-files`. If you don't use a project manager, then add a `.projectile` file at project root will turn that directory into a project. Or, you can set `projectile-require-project-root` to nil and you can use `projectile` in any directory. If you use Helm, you can insert any entry with `C-c C-i` into the current buffer. Have a look at [my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) for demos.